# Tarefa em background e assíncrona em app ionic

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, mobile, assincronismo, background-services

Estou trabalhando com ionic e crie um app onde salvo a localização atual de cada usuário, entretanto, a função que realiza a busca pelas coordenadas do usuário executa quando eu inicio o ciclo de vida da tela "home". 
Eu preciso que essa função seja executada repetidamente em um determinado intervalo de tempo e em background.Já consigo executar o app em background, o único problema encontrado é a execução assíncrona... Eu estou procurando por soluções possíveis para que eu possa implementar...

Comment: Acredito que deve colocar essa função em um service worker

Comment: Obrigado pela sua sugestão Guilherme, encontrei na documentação, vou estudar...